# iOS webview connection error handling

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiwebview

I'm trying to load a url . But sometimes it gives a error url in the following delegate method.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{

    NSURL* url = [request mainDocumentURL];
    NSString* absoluteString = [url absoluteString];
    NSLog(@"%@",absoluteString);}
```

I want to know that how can i cancel the current url request and reload a new url ?

Comment: can you specify the error message that you get

Comment: I'm getting a string(URL) like "https://________.com/ErrorPage.aspx". I want to reload a new url whenever this happens.

Comment: - (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error;   try this delegate and find does you get any error if so please share it

Comment: I'm getting following error:
 Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)" UserInfo=0x1a177470 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://___________.com/ErrorPage.aspx, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://___________.com/ErrorPage.aspx}

I want reload the new url in this case.

Comment: -999 is caused by ErrorCancelled. This means: another request is made before the previous request is completed....if it possible can you add more code snippets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
if([webView isLoading])
    {
        [webView stopLoading];
    }
```

Comment: I think this will help me.

Comment: Wow it too works for me... Please support the answer